# how to forward fill a column values based on the value in another column in same row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to forward fill the amount column based on times column. for example first value is 2800000.0 , i want this value to be filled 6 times.

```
amount      times       
2800000.0    6
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
4750000.0    4         
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0
```

Desired output:

```
amount      times       
2800000.0    6
2800000.0    0   
2800000.0    0   
2800000.0    0   
2800000.0    0   
2800000.0    0   
2800000.0    0   
4750000.0    4         
4750000.0    0   
4750000.0    0   
4750000.0    0   
4750000.0    0   
nan     0    0   
nan     0    0
```

Comment: What is `print (df['amount'].dtype)` ?

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create groups by test non missing values with cumulative sum and pass to [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function with [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with limit by first value of `times` per groups:

```
#if necessary convert strings t onumeric and NaNs
#df['amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['amount'], errors='coerce')

print (df['amount'].dtype)
float64

g = df['amount'].notna().cumsum()

f = lambda x: x['amount'].ffill(limit=x['times'].iat[0])
df['amount'] = df.groupby(g, group_keys=False).apply(f)
print (df)
       amount  times
0   2800000.0      6
1   2800000.0      0
2   2800000.0      0
3   2800000.0      0
4   2800000.0      0
5   2800000.0      0
6   2800000.0      0
7   4750000.0      4
8   4750000.0      0
9   4750000.0      0
10  4750000.0      0
11  4750000.0      0
12        NaN      0
13        NaN      0
```

Comment: @AsmaDamani - Then change `f = lambda x: x['amount'].ffill(limit=x['times'].iat[0])` to  `f = lambda x: x['amount'].ffill(limit=x['times'].iat[0]) if x['times'].iat[0] > 0 else x['amount']`